# Swift - downcast array of arrays won't compile

Tags: ios, swift, casting

How can I downcast array of `AnyObject` **arrays** to array of `String` **arrays**?

i tried the following code:

```
let v1:[[AnyObject]] = [["hello"]] // v1 type is [[AnyObject]]
let v2 = v1 as! [[String]]         // compile error!
```

but this code will not compile with an error:

> 'String' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

if I just try to downcast array of `AnyObject` to array of `String`, it works fine:

```
let v1:[AnyObject] = ["hello"] // v1 type is [AnyObject]
let v2 = v1 as! [String]       // v2 type is [String] as expected
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've already answered your own question. Do in the first code, to each element of the array, what you're successfully doing in the second code. Like this:

```
let v2 = v1.map {$0 as! [String]}
```

Comment: thanks matt, this solved the compiler error )) do you know if it has performance hit? is this a reasonable way to do the casting?

Comment: It does exactly the same thing that casting does. Your `as! [String]` is nothing but a shorthand, a bit of syntactic sugar; the runtime _must_ cycle through the _whole_ array to cast each element individually. This is _exactly_ the same, no more and no less. The only difference is that we didn't get a magic shorthand.

Comment: 10x that was very helpful

Comment: In fact if I remember correctly back in the very earliest days of Swift `map` was the _only_ way to cast an array's elements; there was no `as! [String]` shorthand. And we lived through that period just fine! :)